# phpMyAdmin Export duplicates column name

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, phpmyadmin

I have a MYSQL 8.0.28 server as well as phpMyAdmin running in docker containers. Everything seems to work except that when exporting the database to a dump file through phpMyAdmin one of the views has a syntax error in the dump file.

The SQL for the view has a 'GROUP BY' statement at the end and for whatever reason the last column in the statement is getting duplicated like this:

```
...
GROUP BY
    `db`.`table1`.`column1`,
    `db`.`table2`.`column2`,
    `db`.`table2`.`column3`
```

becomes

```
... 
GROUP BY 
    `db`.`table1`.`column1`, 
    `db`.`table2`.`column2`, 
    `db`.`table2`.`column3``column3`;
```

<sup>*added line break to emphasise additional column name*</sup>

Note that this is a legacy project that I am trying to fix (I did not create this view), and that I am somewhat of a novice when it comes to SQL.

I'm using the latest version of phpMyAdmin but am not averse to downgrading versions if this is a bug with phpMyAdmin

I'm also aware that using MYSQL to dump directly might be better but the users of this project would prefer that it can be done through a web interface.

Comment: I'll add that creating a dump with mysqldump worked as intended, so it actually does appear to be a bug with phpmyadmin

Comment: Sounds like a bug in phpmyadmin; file a bug report.  Meanwhile, switch to the commandline "mysql".

Comment: As I see the space between completely qualified name and the alias is lost.

Comment: MySQL always expands all object names in the view during its creation till complete name qualifying while taken the current database name into account. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d767e3ae08170dfc14f1de485e7a31d2